# Gatsby - run functions during build time

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby with Netlify CMS and need to modify the data received using Gatsby's `useStaticQuery` hook.

For example, in Netlify CMS I allow users to define what Google Fonts they want to use for different typography styles (e.g. h1 to h6, buttons, body text, etc). I then need to import the fonts into the `<head>`, and to do this I run a somewhat expensive function that combines all the font families and weights into a | separated string array (e.g. `"Open+Sans:400,500|Roboto:300|Montserrat:500,600,700"`). It's expensive as I need to combine all the font families and weights while ensuring there are no duplicates.

I have a few other use cases as well. For example, I'm using Material UI and need to pass in a `theme` object to the `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>` component. To do this, I need to modify the data received from `useStaticQuery` to create the `theme` object.

This really only needs to occur at build time as it never changes during run time. Also, at the moment you can't use `useStaticQuery` within `wrapRootElement`, so this function will run for every single page load.

Is there any way to run this function during Gatsby's build time, so that the return value is available as a prop?

Comment: I see that I can create custom schemas and resolvers with Gatsby. I believe that may be the answer - create a query schema like `getGoogleFonts` then run the function in the resolver. I'll try it and will provide an answer if it works.